# Filtering on results of joins if condition met else return value

Tags: sql

I have the below code that essentially pulls out the bill of material for all my companies products that start with A. It works like a charm but I would like to only return rows when the right most column returns a string like 'r30%'. Some products will go 7 levels deep depending on the complexity of the top assembly, while others might only go 2.

I've worked with a couple pre-written codes that include cursor and I think this would be a good use for it but need some help on where to start. I understand the possible speed concerns, but this would only be ran 1 time. Looking to save myself from having to manually scroll through 170,000 lines.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MP.MATERIALID '1',  
            PB.MATERIALID '2', 
            PB2.MATERIALID '3', 
            PB3.MATERIALID '4',
            PB4.MATERIALID '5',
            PB5.MATERIALID '6',
            PB6.MATERIALID '7'
            
    FROM A MP
    INNER JOIN B PB ON PB.BOMID = MP.PBOMID     

        LEFT JOIN A2 mp2 ON mp2.MATERIALID = pb.MATERIALID
        LEFT JOIN B2 pb2 ON pb2.BOMID = mp2.PBOMID

            LEFT JOIN A3 mp3 ON mp3.MATERIALID = pb2.MATERIALID
            LEFT JOIN B3 pb3 ON pb3.BOMID = mp3.PBOMID
        
                LEFT JOIN A4 mp4 ON mp4.MATERIALID = pb3.MATERIALID
                LEFT JOIN B4 pb4 ON pb4.BOMID = mp4.PBOMID
        
                    LEFT JOIN A5 mp5 ON mp5.MATERIALID = pb4.MATERIALID
                    LEFT JOIN B5 pb5 ON pb5.BOMID = mp5.PBOMID
            
                        LEFT JOIN A6 mp6 ON mp6.MATERIALID = pb5.MATERIALID
                        LEFT JOIN B6 pb6 ON pb6.BOMID = mp6.PBOMID

    WHERE MP.MATERIALID LIKE 'A%'
    ORDER BY PB.MATERIALID, PB2.MATERIALID, PB3.MATERIALID, pb4.MATERIALID, pb5.MATERIALID, pb6.MATERIALID
```

Comment: Please edit your question to update the tags showing the correct database management system (Oracle, MSSQL, etc)

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output in text format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What RDBMS (Oracle, MSSQL, ...) is this, and what version?  Many of the RDBMS nowadays have BOM functions for exactly this purpose.  And you have all these views in your database? (A2, B2, A3, B3, ...) ???

Comment: I applied the SQL tag, thought that was sufficient. I changed the table names for confidentiality reasons (aka warm and fuzzies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something quite simple with `coalesce`, which finds the first non-null entry in a list by starting backwards:

```
where 
coalesce (pb6.materialid,pb5.materialid,pb4.materialid,pb3.materialid,pb2.materialid,pb1.materialid) 
like  'r30%'`
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.